# Win 8.1 Bing map control is showing access denied image

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, bing-maps

I am creating a Windows 8.1 application. I am using Bing amp control in it.
But it is showing access denied image on the Bin map control.

```
  <map:Map x:Name="MapControl" Height="480"  Width="475"   IsEnabled="{Binding IsMapEnabled}" 
                                            Credentials="{StaticResource BingMapKey}" ManipulationMode="All" ZoomLevel="3" 
                                            ShowNavigationBar="False" ShowScaleBar="False" ShowBuildings="True"  ViewRestriction="OneWorldOnly">
                                            <map:Map.Center>
                                                <map:Location Latitude="{Binding CurrentLocation.Latitude}" Longitude="{Binding CurrentLocation.Longitude}"/>
                                            </map:Map.Center>
```

[image]

Credentials are also given. What is wrong there? If anybody knows the reason  please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the region settings. Certain regions are blocked due to geopolitical issues. This is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj670541.aspx

One way around this is to set the HomeRegion property of the map to US or some other supported 2 letter country code.

Comment: yes . If i set HoemRegion to US it works well. Thanks

Comment: The Windows 8.1 map control is nearing end of support (Windows 8 support in general ends in January). Use the Windows UWP map control which is built into the Windows 10 UWP SDK. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn642089.aspx